# Nftables sepparate rules for different ip on the same interface

Tags: network-interface, ip, nftables, netfilter

I have a server with 2 public IP addresses linked to it. However, both of them are on the same interface (`ens3`). I think it called IP-aliasing.

```
ens3:
    altname enp0s3
    inet <public ip 1>/32 brd <public ip 1> scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet <public ip 2>/32 brd <public ip 2> scope global ens3:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Is it possible to configure `nftables` such that connecting to ssh port is allowed only via one of the public IPs. `iff` doesn't understand labels of the form `ens3:xx`. And using `ip saddr` won't work either since it will contain IP of the machine that tries to connect via ssh.

Comment: Then use ip daddr?

Comment: Iif checks index, try iifname. Or just check destination ip. Also read this https://serverfault.com/questions/985158/what-is-the-different-between-iifname-and-iif-in-nftables